# C# Argument cannot convert int to string or string to int

Tags: c#, methods, arguments

I'm trying to debug this code, but in third method it's not allowing me to use different data types.  In my textbook, the example shows them using different data types as an argument.  Why isn't it allowing me to do so?  I'm sure that this code has other issues, but I can't even debug them until I clear the errors.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WP_Week3_Problem2
{
    public partial class Problem2 : Form
    {
        public Problem2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        int[] productID = { 1234, 5678, 5677, 8765, 2345, 8734 };
        double[] productPrice = { 5.55, 20.0, 40.0, 56.34, 78.10, 98.0 };
        String[] productName = { "Pencil", "Backpack", "MessengerBag", "RoomHeater", "SewingMachine", "Decorative Lamp" };

        private void Problem2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void buttonLoadTable_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            labelOutput.Text = "ProdID     Price        ProdName";
            for (int i = 0; i < productID.Length; i = i + 1)
            {
                labelOutput.Text += String.Format("\n {0}       {1}       {2} ", productID[i], productPrice[i].ToString("C"), productName[i]);
            }
        }

        private void buttonSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int prodID = Convert.ToInt32(textBoxID.Text);
            String prodName = textBoxName.Text;
            double prodPrice = Convert.ToDouble(textBoxPrice.Text);
            SearchProducts(prodID);
            SearchProducts(prodName);
            SearchProducts(prodID, prodName, prodPrice);
        }
        private void SearchProducts(int prodID)
        {
            int prodMinus = prodID - 1;
            int idExists = Array.IndexOf(productID, prodMinus);
            if (idExists == -1)
            {
                labelOutput.Text = "That product ID is invalid.\nPlease enter a valid product ID";
                textBoxID.Text = "";
            }
        }
        private void SearchProducts(String prodName)
        {
            String nameExists = Array.IndexOf(productName, prodName).ToString();
            bool isName = true;
            if (nameExists == "Pencil")
                isName = true;
            else if (nameExists == "Backpack")
                isName = true;
            else if (nameExists == "MessengerBag")
                isName = true;
            else if (nameExists == "RoomHeater")
                isName = true;
            else if (nameExists == "SewingMachine")
                isName = true;
            else if (nameExists == "Decorative Lamp")
                isName = true;
            else
                isName = false;
            labelOutput.Text = "This Product Name is invalid.\nPlease enter a valid Product Name";
        }
        private void SearchProducts(String prodName, int prodID, double prodPrice)
        {
            labelOutput.Text = String.Format("Your Product ID of {0} is a {2} and it costs: {1}", prodID, prodName, prodPrice.ToString("C"));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: C# is a statically typed language.  You can't simply "use different types" wherever you want.  What line is throwing this error?  What are the types you're using vs. what it expects?  What are you trying to accomplish on that line?

Comment: Line 45 is where I declare the method, Line 79 is where I try to use the three data types in a string.format

Comment: @Bob Nice, let me count the lines in your post :)

Comment: Hey, he asked...

Comment: Yeah.  Your post doesnt have line numbers.  Please read [ask] and take the [tour].  There are some 14 answers on your past 7 posts - which means you have gotten plenty of help/answers - but not a one has been accepted.

Comment: @Plutonix accepted....not sure what that means.  I always +1 good answers

Comment: @Bob [How does accepting an answer work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Comment: Yeah, thats why I suggest you take the [tour].  It explains stuff.  I duunoi what you mean by `+1 answers` but it typically means upvoting - clicking the up or dn arrow next to a good/bad post.  You've only recently gotten that privileged.  Voting and accepting answers helps others find good posts.  Its a way you can help others even if you are not in a position to post answers.

Comment: on a related note, it's telling me that:  double prodPrice = Convert.ToDouble(textBoxPrice.Text);  that the input string is not in the correct format....

Comment: @Bob Just wait.. I am trying to see your window with my crystal ball, to answer what is wrong with the text in  `textBoxPrice.Text`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also usefully do with some error handling on the text box conversions - it is **never** a good plan to take a text box and expect the user to simply enter valid data:

```
    private void buttonSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        bool process = true;
        String prodName = textBoxName.Text;
        int prodID;
        double prodPrice;
        try
        {
            prodID = Convert.ToInt32(textBoxID.Text);
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error in product ID", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            process = false;        
        }
        try
        {
            prodPrice = Convert.ToDouble(textBoxPrice.Text);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error in product price", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            process = false;

        }
        if (process)
        {
            SearchProducts(prodID);
            SearchProducts(prodName);
            SearchProducts(prodID, prodName, prodPrice);
        }
    }
```

Edit:

I did forget to say that you could replace Convert with the class parsers, this avoids the need for a try/catch:

```
if (!Int32.TryParse(textBoxID.Text, out prodID))
{
    process = false;
    // message method of choice to tell user of error
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change this line

`SearchProducts(prodID, prodName, prodPrice);`

to this one

`SearchProducts(prodName, prodID, prodPrice);`

The SearchProducts method expects String, int and double parameters, but you passed an int, string and double.